# #DIV error in Google Sheet related to Pivot table

Tags: google-sheets, error-handling, pivot-table, formula

I am trying to fix an error in **googlesheet** especially related to Pivot table. Especially when I make extra calculations from the Pivot table I get the **#Div error** when I filter on basis of few parameters. But if I make it without any filters I do get proper results.

I am looking for a solution where the calculations can take particular cell values with respect to cell column name only. So I can make a better calculations without any type of filters or shiftings. This is a dynamic case.

Can anyone suggest any better answer?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h1TdFLj3JyK6-oxOOswuWDx4YixzG51H2rWgK0BbD2s/edit#gid=925622507

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 I have added a sheet with demo data. You can check the 1st table with #Diverror.

Answer (score 1):

#DIV error is the result of trying to divide an empty cell with another empty cell

[image]

it's a standard issue equivalent to dividing 0 with 0. such math is not logical and google sheets will flag it as an error to alert you.

however, the true culprit is that #REF error:

[image]

filters of pivot table cant produce/create additional columns. pivot table will just roll out data wherever it needs. in your scenario pivot table attempts to roll out date into 3 columns but only two columns there are empty. 3rd column (C) is filled with data/formulae and pivot table cannot move data or delete data so if there is no space to roll out it will #REF error to alert you that something went wrong.

possible solution: move C, D columns to the right. if you are not able to predict how many columns will filter of pivot data roll out into then have som extra space between and for the visuals you can hide those empty columns

Comment: Is it good to move all the time when need to filter out do you thing? Also, if there are N number of columns in pivot table it will be always problems if some formulas used to calculate from the pivot. Also, If I link with another pivot table values again it would be the same problem. Hope you can think of the issues what I am facing. I am looking for a solution where the calculations can take cell values with respect to cell column name.